# How to return plain string as JSON in ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In process of migrating from .net framework and are struggling with a difference of response serialization.

Everything here seems to indicate that by default a response will go out via the json serializer.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-5.0 but when returning a simple string value all our endpoints have the content type of "text/plain" so the text isn't surrounded by quotes.

Given this basic controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SanityController : ControllerBase
{
    public SanityController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet0]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Where are the quotes?";
    }
}
```

And our Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

...

// Tried this as well, not sure what the difference even is between this an AddJsonOptions, seemed to work the same.
//builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
//{
//    options.SerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
//    options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
//    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
//    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
//});

...

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
    });

...

app.Run();
```

But the Content-Type returned for all of our endpoints that return strings is just "text/plain". We tried changing the Accept header on our client from
`application/json, text/plain, */*` to `application/json, text/plain;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8` but it would still return text. Only if we only set it to just `application/json` would it finally return json. But this doesn't help when hitting it directly from a browser window where it will again just return it as "text/plain".

We also found could also put `[Produces("application/json")]` on the controller method and that would also work.

But considering 99% of all our endpoints should return JSON with barely a handful returning text or xml, is there not a way to change the aggressive default for a string response to be `application/json` app wide like it was with asp.net?

Comment: How do you want your string to be converted as json?

Comment: Quotes. text/plaid returns `Where are the quotes?` where application/json returns `"Where are the quotes"`.

Comment: Have you tried ```public IActionResult Get() { return Json("Where are the quotes?"); }``` - UNTESTED!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove [`StringOutputFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.stringoutputformatter?view=aspnetcore-7.0) (if needed add it to the end with `options.OutputFormatters.Add(new StringOutputFormatter());` after `RemoveType` call):

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<StringOutputFormatter>();
});
```

Comment: We wondered about this approach but since there were a couple instances where we did actually want a plain response we were hoping to find something better. But considering the number of cases is just a few compared to the everything else might be worth just making those few support being returned as json and call it a day if there's not way to keep both.

Comment: @Wrightboy try removing it and than adding it back as written in the answer, i.e. `options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<StringOutputFormatter>(); options.OutputFormatters.Add(new StringOutputFormatter());`, this will add the string formatter back at the end of the pipeline and it should work when plain text is requested. Also you can always use `Json` or `Content` helper methods to enforce the required output media type.

Comment: Just to clarify, that doing what @GuruStron suggested, will change the order of precedence during content negotiation. So, the precedence will be for application/json instead of text/plain. Which is probably appropriate for your use case.

Comment: @GuruStron That's hilarious, and it worked perfect. Makes sense that it would allow the json formatter to move to the top spot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

My approach:

```
string json = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return new ContentResult()
{
    Content = json,
    ContentType = "application/json"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

String value is a valid JSON, however it is confusing to ASP.Net core and it can't know if you intended it to be an application/json or a text/plain.
What you can do in this case, is to specify that you need a application/json in the request levraging [content negotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-7.0#content-negotiation-2).

using the Accept to be `application/json` will make asp.net core return `application/json` instead of text/plain.

[image: Postman screenshot]
And the proper header.
[image: Headers]

Or else if you want to do it in a global manner, you can remove the
plain/text formatter :

```
services.AddControllers(options => options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<StringOutputFormatter>());
```

This, of course, will prevent you from never being able to send text/plain back. even if you set the Produces Attribute, or send an Accept header with text/plain.